# how to check only one checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using a gridview and my problem is that a user can select only one checkbox in the grid if the user select second checkbox previous will we unchecked . i try javascript but that not works for me can you please help me how can i do this . Below is my gridview

```
    <data:EntityGridView ID="gvService" Width="100%"  DataKeyNames="PriceSystemID" runat="server"
                                            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCommand="gvServices_ItemCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                            OnRowDeleting="gvService_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvService_RowCancelingEdit" 
                                            >
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataServiceTypeId1"  DataSourceID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource"
                                                            DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ServiceTypeId" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServiceTypeID") %>' Width="200px"
                                                            AppendNullItem="true" Required="true" NullItemText="< Please Choose ...>" ErrorText="Required" />
                                                        <data:ServiceTypesDataSource ID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource" runat="server"
                                                            SelectMethod="GetAll" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataServiceTypeId2" DataSourceID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource"
                                                             DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ServiceTypeId" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="true"
                                                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServiceTypeID") %>' AppendNullItem="true" Required="true"
                                                            NullItemText="< Please Choose ...>" ErrorText="Required" />
                                                        <data:ServiceTypesDataSource ID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource" runat="server"
                                                            SelectMethod="GetAll" />
                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                      <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataServiceTypeId3" DataSourceID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ServiceTypeId" Width="200px"
                                                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServiceTypeID") %>' AppendNullItem="true" Required="true"
                                                            NullItemText="< Please Choose ...>" ErrorText="Required" />
                                                        <data:ServiceTypesDataSource ID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource" runat="server"
                                                            SelectMethod="GetAll" />
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDefault" Checked='<%# Bind("IsDefault") %>'   
                                                            runat="server" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDefault" Checked='<%# Bind("IsDefault") %>' runat="server"   />
                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDefault" Checked='<%# Bind("IsDefault") %>' runat="server"   />

                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

' CausesValidation="false">

```
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
 </EmptyDataTemplate>

    </data:EntityGridView>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery ? - you can use RadioButtons -

Comment: problem with that because i not want to use any jquery or java scrip in my application only by code part i have permission to use in application .

Answer (score 1):

One basic question (which may be your answer) : Why use check-box, if user can select only ONE. Use Radio buttons instead with proper grouping and the browser will take care of single selection. Hope I am clear enough. Check-boxes are used when user has multiple choices to select from, otherwise, use Radio buttons for single selection.

Comment: yes you say right but here is checkbox using this grid they can create a collection of row after that any one will be applicable for the user . That the admin wants

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understood your requirement. Wherever you say that there is a single choice for users, you should put Radio buttons instead of check-boxes. I see no point giving check boxes and then validating for single select.

Comment: Thanks to give me quick response . There is no problem i use checkbox or radio button . According to you if i use radio button how can i use that programmatic only one radio button will checked by the user. Is any programmatic solution for this . no javascript

Comment: Please read `GroupName` property description on http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_radiobutton.asp and go through the complete tutorial to get acquainted with Radio buttons in asp.net, if not already acquainted.